# The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/path/on/project/cargo" does not exist

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-analyzer

My remote server environment is Windows.

After installing rust-analyzer in Visual Studio Code, I tried to use the plugin to generate `Run test` commands in the code.

However, I encountered an error similar to the following:

```
Executing task: d:\path\to\projectA\cargo test --package projectA --bin projectA -- logic::test::tests::test_a_func --exact --nocapture

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "d:\path\to\projectA\cargo" does not exist.
```

the `d:\path\to\projectA\` was generated by `cargo new projectA`.

and when I change to `projectB`, do the same thing, I also encountered the similar error, but the path just change to `projectB`:

```
Executing task: d:\path\to\projectB\cargo test --package projectB --bin projectB -- logic::test::tests::test_b_func --exact --nocapture

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "d:\path\to\projectB\cargo" does not exist.
```

I have already made the following settings in VSCode, but didn't work:

```json
{
    "rust-analyzer.server.extraEnv": {
        "RUSTUP_HOME": "C:/Users/name/.rustup",
        "CARGO_HOME": "C:/Users/name/.cargo",
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Windows PowerShell",
    "rust-analyzer.runnableEnv": {
        "PATH": "C:/Users/name/.cargo/bin"
    },
}
```

Can I configure rust-analyzer to use the specific `C:/Users/name/.cargo/bin/cargo.exe` file?
Or have any other solution?

Comment: Is [Rustup](https://rustup.rs/) properly installed? Does the command `where cargo` give you a path to the executable? Related links: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/9721 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/11673

Comment: @E_net4 yes, I can use `cargo -V` and `rustup -V` to get there version: cargo 1.67.1 (8ecd4f20a 2023-01-10), rustup 1.25.2 (17db695f1 2023-02-01). When I ran the `where.exe cargo` command in the terminal, the terminal did give me the paths of the executables.  In contrast to the related links, his cargo executable path does not contain the project path.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is an issue with the Visual Studio Code Extension 'SSH Remote'.

I found a solution in this discussion: [link here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/14381)

Answer (score 0):

Close all instances of VS Code after installing rust-analyzer, then open the project once again and execute, It worked for me